# Calculating bounds with multiple random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this problem:

Suppose there are 4 students (who we'll refer to as A, B, C, and D) in a class and each student is equally likely to have been born in any of the twelve months of the year. For any subset T of the students, RT be the event that that all the students in T are born in January. (Note that the event RT doesn't imply that students that are not in T are not born in January.) For example R{A,B} is the event that students A and B were both born in January. Let X be the random variable corresponding to the number of students born in January.

(RT here is supposed to be with T as a subscript but I do not know how to do that on stack)

**I am trying to figure out this following problem:**

Let *Xi* be the number of students born on the *ith* month of the year, e.g., X1 = X, 
and let Y = max(X1, X2, X3, ... , X12). What's the exact value of P(Y >= 3)?

I am really stuck on how to do begin this process. I was thinking that I should find the expected value of each X1,X2,X3...X12. But I am not sure exactly how to do this/if I have to do that.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many symbols, but there are only $4$ students. We want $\Pr(Y\ge 4)$, which is $\Pr(Y=3)+\Pr(Y=4)$.

We go after $\Pr(Y=4)$ first, since it is easier. We want the probability the students were all born in the same month. The month can be chosen in $\binom{12}{1}$ ways. If all months are equally likely (unlikely!), and we have independence, the the probability the students were all born in a given month is $\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^4$. Thus $\Pr(Y=4)=\binom{12}{1}\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^4$.

For $\Pr(Y=3)$, the lucky month with $3$ births can be chosen in $\binom{12}{1}$ ways. The lucky $3$ students who were born that month can be chosen in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways. The probability these students were born in that month is $\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^3$. The remaining month can be chosen in $\binom{11}{1}$ ways, and the probability the remaining student was born that month is $\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)$. Thus $\Pr(Y=3)=\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^4\binom{11}{1}\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)$.

Finally, calculate $\Pr(Y=4)+\Pr(Y=3)$.

**Remark:** We can do the same thing in what looks superficially another way. Have the students write down their birth month, in the order A then B then C then D. Under our assumptions, all $12^4$ possible strings are equally likely.

Now we need to count the **favourables**, the number of ways that the sequence written down has all months the same, plus the number of ways that the sequence can have $3$ months the same and one different.

By the same argument as above, the number of strings with all months equal is $\binom{12}{1}$.

The number of strings with $3$ identical months is $\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{11}{1}$.

Add, and for the probability divide by $12^4$.

Comment: Thank you, except what if there are more than four students? The four students may have been for another part of this problem I am not sure it apply's here anymore. Is there a more general way of figuring this out?

Comment: The general problem for arbitrary numbers of students can be solved, by Inclusion/Exclusion and in other ways. Note that if there are $25$ or more students, then automatically we have for sure that $Y\ge 3$.